# Robotframework and Saucelabs integration

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to integrate my robotframework test with saucelabs. I just used open browser keyword and passed the remote url and desired capabilities values.

```
Open Browser  https://saucelabs.com/  ie  remote_url=${REMOTE_URL}  desired_capabilities=browserName:internet explorer,version:9.0,platform:Windows 7
```

Got the below error

> Opening browser 'ie' to base url 'https://saucelabs.com/' through
>   remote server at 'desired_capabilities=browserName:internet
>   explorer,version:9.0,platform:Windows 7' failed [ WARN ] Can't take
>   screenshot. No open browser found | FAIL |
>   java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
>   desired_capabilities=browserName:internet
>   explorer,version:9.0,platform:Windows 7

I tried to pass the desired capabilities in different format and got the same error. This framework is set up in eclipse using jython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Browser  https://saucelabs.com/  browserName=ie  remoteUrl=${REMOTE_URL}  desiredCapabilities=platform:Windows 7,browserName:internet explorer,version:9.0,username:${username},accessKey:${accessKey}

Define/pass the values of the variables before using the above statement.